# How to get SQL data via PHP into D3 matrix

Tags: php, sql

I've been looking for this answer a few weeks now and no succes.

In D3 to build a simple graph I might use a matrix like:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js">
</script>

<script>
   var matrix = [
          [1000, 10000, 0, 0, 1000, 3000, 4000, 0, 4000,1000, 2000],
          [2000, 2000, 2000, 0, 0, 4000, 1000, 4000, 4000,1000, 2000],
          [1000, 2000, 0, 0, 3000, 0, 1000, 4000, 4000,1000, 2000],
          [1000, 2000, 4000, 0, 3000, 4000, 1000, 4000, 4000,1000, 2000],
          [1000, 2000, 4000, 0, 0, 4000, 1000, 4000, 4000,1000, 2000],
          [10000, 0, 0, 0, 7000, 2000, 1000, 4000, 4000,1000, 2000],
          [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 3000, 4000, 1000, 4000, 4000,1000, 2000],
          [0, 2000, 3000, 4000, 3000, 4000, 1000, 4000, 4000,1000, 2000],
          [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 3000, 4000, 1000, 4000, 4000,1000, 2000],
          [1000, 1000, 1000, 3000, 4000, 7000, 1000, 4000, 4000,1000, 2000],
          [1000, 1000, 1000, 7000, 3000, 4000, 1000, 4000, 4000,1000, 2000]
       ];
</script>
```

What I'm looking for is to have these numbers coming from my SQL query, like:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Item-1, 
                              Item-2, 
                              Item-3, 
                              .... 
                         FROM $tbl_name 
                         WHERE Organization = 'SBM Offshore N.V.'");
```

I would appreciate any help or direction towards an answer.

Many thanks.

Comment: First you need to exaplain in your question how is that data arranged on your table, is it number by number? is it each element of the matrix? So show us your table structure and a sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Data is coming from a simple MySQL database. It will be called like:

```
<?php

$host = "....";
$LoginNaam = "....";
$Password = "....";
$db_name = "....";
$tbl_name = "....";

$con = mysql_connect($host, $LoginNaam, $Password);
if (!$con)
  {
  die(mysql_error("can't connect"));
  }
mysql_select_db($db_name, $con) or die(mysql_error("can't find database"));

$result = mysql_query(" SELECT Meldingsplichtige, Aantal_aandelen, Kapitaalbelang, Stemrecht FROM $tbl_name WHERE Uitgevende_instelling = 'SBM Offshore N.V.' ");

?>
```

It is one tabel with a few columns and rows. Each row might hold a type VARCHAR or INT.

When it is the INT type it need to be used to draw a line or graph. For the type VARCHAR I would use it as a text element.

Just for testing purposes, I could build a Database with one column and only integers.

Thanks for the help.